# Artifactory upload with checksum

Tags: curl, artifactory, checksum

If you upload an artifact to Artifactory and don't provide a checksum, it gives this warning:

[image: Screenshot, Artifactory, Fix Checksum]

How do you upload with `curl` and include a checksum?

Comment: I know you specifically asked about uploading with curl, and you already got an answer for it, but if it is relevant for you, when uploading withJFrog CLI, it automatically calculates and appends the checksums to the upload request.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This feature currently isn't well documented, an example is found on this page:

https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-are-client-checksum-server-checksum-and-checksum-policy-in-local-repositories/

Simply add the following to the curl command: `"--header "X-Checksum-<type>:${CHECKSUM}"`

Sha1

```
CHECKSUM=$(shasum -a 1 foo.zip | awk '{ print $1 }')

curl --header "X-Checksum-Sha1:${CHECKSUM}" --upload-file "foo.zip -u "admin:<apikey>" -v https://artifactory.example.com/foo/
```

MD5

```
CHECKSUM=$(md5sum foo.zip | awk '{ print $1 }')

curl --header "X-Checksum-MD5:${CHECKSUM}" --upload-file "foo.zip -u "admin:<apikey>" -v https://artifactory.example.com/foo/
```

---

Or provide both checksums at once

```
ARTIFACT_MD5_CHECKSUM=$(md5sum foo.zip | awk '{print $1}')
ARTIFACT_SHA1_CHECKSUM=$(shasum -a 1 foo.zip | awk '{ print $1 }')
curl --upload-file "foo.zip" \
--header "X-Checksum-MD5:${ARTIFACT_MD5_CHECKSUM}" \
--header "X-Checksum-Sha1:${ARTIFACT_SHA1_CHECKSUM}" \
-u "admin:<apikey>" \
-v https://artifactory.example.com/foo/
```

Unfortunatley, uploading with the sha256 doesn't work with curl [because of a bug](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-9871)

Comment: Just in case it doesn't work for you beware that uploading checksums using headers is available only since Artifactory version 2.3.2 See: https://www.mail-archive.com/artifactory-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02203.html     For previous versions you will have to upload checksupms separately

Comment: The link has apparently been deprecated. The current documentation appears to be over at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactbyChecksum

Answer (score 16):

This is working for me in 7.4.3 for MD5, SHA1 and SHA256.

```
for file in $(find a_folder -type f)
do
    ARTIFACT_MD5_CHECKSUM=$(md5sum $file | awk '{print $1}')
    ARTIFACT_SHA1_CHECKSUM=$(shasum -a 1 $file | awk '{ print $1 }')
    ARTIFACT_SHA256_CHECKSUM=$(shasum -a 256 $file | awk '{ print $1 }')

    echo curl --upload-file $file \
            --header "X-Checksum-MD5:${ARTIFACT_MD5_CHECKSUM}" \
            --header "X-Checksum-Sha1:${ARTIFACT_SHA1_CHECKSUM}" \
            --header "X-Checksum-Sha256:${ARTIFACT_SHA256_CHECKSUM}" \
            -u "admin:${APIKEY}" \
            -v http://URL/$file
done
```

Comment: This works. For the warning to disappear, only SHA1 and SHA256 are required as of Artifactory 6.18.1. MD5 checksum is accepted, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not allowed to comment I will post a clarification as an answer.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009688/artifactory-upload-with-checksum/40009689#comment102788190_40009689) suggests that the `Deploy Artifact by Checksum` API is the documentation regarding uploads with checksum verification. But that is only valid for uploads of artifacts that already exist in Artifactory.
[As documented](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactbyChecksum), it will reject new artifact uploads with a 404.

Comment: If you tried with the header -H "X-Checksum-Deploy:true". If that is the case, it will upload only if the content exists. Just try without this header or with -H "X-Checksum-Deploy:false"

Comment: Looks like the X-Checksum-Deploy header behaviour is documented now.

"If the X-Checksum-Deploy header is set to false, the artifact will be uploaded successfully with a 201 response, even if it didn't exist before, and submitted checksums will have status Uploaded: Identical."